# actionscript to java (red5)

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, red5

I'm trying to migrate an existing actionscript program (server part) to java (red5).
However, I'm blocked with the following code :

```
Client.prototype.requestInterview = function () { };
```

Does anyone know what is the equivalent of Client.prototype in red5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining object (function in your case) in "prototype", you are basically defining class member. In your case it would be regular instance methods (public in java)

Comment: because I'm not familiar with actionscript, I'm wondering if prototype is an existing object of the class Client or not. 
Otherwise, do I have to create a java class Client with an object named prototype (of which type ?) and then define a public method requestInterview ?

Thanks